# getting time in GLUT cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, time, glut

I want to write a time program in GLUT. My program is a timer that controls by clicks. But I don't know how get time in second in GLUT?. but this code do not work Truth.
the t variable in follow codes is seconds after click .
this is part of my codes:

```
void time(int extra)
    {
    t++;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000,time,0);

    }

void idle()
{   
time(1);
}
void mouse(int btn, int st, int x, int y)
{
if(btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && st == GLUT_DOWN)
glutIdleFunc(idle);
if(btn == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && st ==GLUT_DOWN)
glutIdleFunc(NULL);
}
```

Comment: "T variable", I don't see any `T` variable.

Comment: OpenGL is a rendering library. It doesn't deal with time.

Comment: then, how can I do this function?

Comment: Is any function in opengl that gives seconds ?

Comment: @Ava Bahari: How did you decide that you want to use OpenGL to solve this problem?

Comment: I want do this by opengl only

Comment: @AvaBahari: What part of "OpenGL is a *rendering library*" do you not understand? It's for drawing stuff, not measuring time. Libraries exist for different purposes; OpenGL also doesn't have any file loading functions, internet access functions, or the ability to spawn other processes. OpenGL is for drawing; getting the time has nothing to do with the process of drawing itself. Yes, it can be used to help with animation, but that is *not* the responsibility of OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. To get time in second you can call `time` function. here is an example which demonstrates the use of this function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t seconds;

  seconds = time (NULL);
  printf ("%ld hours since January 1, 1970", seconds/3600);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I want do this by opengl functions.

Comment: Can you explain why it has to be openGL function? Knowing that it is easier to help.

Comment: Because some Cpp libraries make problem for runnig opengl

Comment: If there isn't any way I should use time_t but if exist a function for doing this in opengl I will use them.

Comment: OK, now I understand. If you get compiler errors pointing to gl.h, this is because there are some things like WINGDI which are used in gl.h but are only defined in some other header files. Include windows.h before including gl.h. refer to this page for more information: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Platform_specifics:_Windows

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL only handles rendering, nothing else. You might be confusing OpenGL with GLUT, which is something different. If you want high-precision timing, GLUT is not the way to go, and neither is its modern replacement freeGLUT. I recommend [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) for that purpose.